# updating two tables in one mysql query

Tags: mysql

I've had a nice little bit of php/mysql working at the end of an AJAX call, which updates a table. I now need to change this update so that PART of the post updates one table and the other part updates another table. I'm unclear how to do this correctly. This is the code as to what I have had working to date:

```
if(isset($_POST['p2From'])) {
    $userInput = $_POST['p2From'];
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET `p2From` = :userinput, `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}
```

What I want to do is effectively achieve this:

```
if(isset($_POST['p2From'])) {
    $userInput = $_POST['p2From'];
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_AIGtabs SET `p2From` = :userinput WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}
```

And

```
if(isset($_POST['p2From'])) {
    $userInput = $_POST['p2From'];
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey SET `lastModified` = :time WHERE `appID` = :appid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}
```

However I'd like to ultimetly achieve this all in one update query as opposed to two. I'm sure this is possible, though I am very unclear how to perform this in one mysql query. Can someone show me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Multiple-table Update syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

```
if(isset($_POST['p2From'])) {
    $userInput = $_POST['p2From'];
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            UPDATE $database.app_$applicationKey
            JOIN $database.app_AIGtabs on $database.app_$applicationKey.`appID` = $database.app_AIGtabs.`appID`
            SET `lastModified` = :time, `p2From` = :userinput
            WHERE $database.app_$applicationKey.`appID` = :appid;");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);
        $stmt->bindParam(':time', time(), PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->bindParam(':appid', $appID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
}
```

Comment: ANSI JOIN syntax is preferable

Comment: Thank you machee, that worked perfectly with only one slight change required - double quotes were required instead of single inside the prepare statement. :)